# Rails Associations don't work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I've read through many tutorials, and copied their code exactly, yet what they claim works for them doesn't work for me.

I'm making a most basic "has_many" and "belongs_to" association, but rails refuses to acknowledge any association whatsoever.

A user "has_many" emails. Emails "belong_to" user. Here's my code:

user.rb

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  unloadable

  has_many :emails
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :emails,
    :allow_destroy => true,
  #  :reject_if     => :all_blank
end
```

email.rb

```
class Email < ActiveRecord::Base
  unloadable

  belongs_to :user
end
```

Then, in the console:

```
User.emails.build
NoMethodError: undefined method `emails' for #<Class:0x00000006c16e88>
```

Indeed, this "NoMethodError" persists no matter what.

As of now, my guess is that a capacitor in my hardware burnt out while I was installing rails, causing everything to work except this one thing. Or maybe it's something else :p

EDIT:

Another console attempt:

```
my_user = User.new
my_user.emails.build
```

Also results in an undefined "emails" method.

I noticed that my original user class has a bad comma at the end; removing that, I get this error:

```
ActiveRecord::UnknownAttributeError: unknown attribute 'user_id' for Email.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you'll need to make sure you have a `user_id` attribute on your email table in the database. If you don't have one, you can add it with a migration.

Then, you need to tell Rails which instance of a user's emails you want to look at. So, you'll need to make sure you have a user in the database (`user = User.create`) and then that user's emails can be found using `user.emails`.

Comment: So making it "belongs_to" doesn't already generate user_id? interesting

Comment: @ineedahero: [Read more](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-belongs-to-association) about it.

Answer (score 1):

You're confusing the concept of classes and instances. You need an instance of the `User` class in order to build associated relations. The error you're getting (`NoMethodError: undefined method emails for #<Class:0x00000006c16e88>`) hints to this, since it's telling you you're trying to call the method `emails` on a Class object.

Try something like:

```
my_user = User.new
my_user.emails.build
```

Comment: I tried that too, same error: undefined method "emails"

Answer (score 1):

Please use like this

```
@email = User.first.emails.build
```

Comment: result: undefined method `emails' for #<User:0x00000004c34318>

Comment: please check after remove unloadable this will be work

Comment: Woah, in my user class I had a trailing comma that caused an error -- but now I get this error: "ActiveRecord::UnknownAttributeError: unknown attribute 'user_id' for Email"

Comment: add the user_id field in your email table